# как вытащить файлы

Tags: macos, macbook

Мне по крупному повезло, мой старенький мак 16 год, про с тачбаром(именно с тачбаром с этого года впаяли все в плату: ссд, оперативу и их не вытащить с него), так же у макбука разбит экран и нету на нем macOS...
В итоге мне надо восстановить с ссд очень важные файлы. Как это сделать?
Да хотя бы как поставить Макос на него обратно ? При условии, что на экран через провод не выводит изображение(так как оказывается нужна Макос ему для этого), так же нельзя подключить его в режиме внешнего диска к другому маку опять же из-за того, что нету Макоси на нем.

Возможно кто-нибудь знает решение данной проблемы? Пробовать в слепую ставить Макос на него ? Но как ? Тоже неизвестно как это сделать.

Comment: Установка через флешку макоси помогло оживить монитор. Осталось восстановить файлы, но говорят это невозможно сделать...